How to real-time stream or seek in log files (tail -f) stored in azure blobs
When testing logging using Loki and Promtail, I noticed that tailing from azure blob storage was not working properly. It starts to tail the first few lines, then stops till a new blob file is written (azure creates log files on an hourly basis.)
The setup is as follows: a managed cluster writes Kubernetes audit logs + other Azure AKS audit logs via “Azure Diagnostics Logs” to blob containers of an Azure Storage Accounts in JSON format. From there, using Azure CSI the storage containers get mounted to persistent volumes of Pods on a local Minikube cluster, which get scraped by Promtail.
The problems seem to have to do with the approach of mounting the azure storage containers via volumes. For this reason, I try to avoid mounting altogether. I am now testing with Promail set up locally on a Linux machine (without a Kubernetes cluster).
I need to live tail diagnostics logs stored in the azure blob storage in a manner similar to tailing files stored locally on the file system. If normal tailing works, then Promtail can do the scraping to Loki as expected.
I found a Windows application that seems to do a similar thing, but I use Linux.
Is there a way/library/tool to live tail azure blobs from Linux without having to manually write code that uses azure triggers or mount volumes?
Ideally it will integrate well with logging frameworks like Loki.
Notes:
1- I tried tailing sidecar which sends the logs to stdout of the sidecar, which then gets scraped by Promtail. It works better than normal tailing with Promtail alone, but still quits tailing logs after a while.
2- When I use Azure Event Hubs for directly streaming audit logs to Promtail on the fly (rather than using Storage Accounts for archiving logs, that get mounted to local cluster Pods), everything works fine and log entries get scraped instantaneously.

Can you add more in detail what you tried?
